# How to allow custom rules in Game Engine design?

Tags: components, game-engine, rule-engine

So I'm working on building a 2D game engine for tower defense games. I am using an Entity Component System (ECS) design in my game, which allows for more flexibility and extensibility. However, I'm confused as to how I would go about implementing custom user defined rules. For example, the user may want a rule that says that when two specific entities collide, cause an explosion with a certain radius. Or she may want a rule that says that when the health of a certain entity reaches a certain point, it's speed increases by a certain amount. Or lets say that when two other entities collide, the Level is automatically over and move on to the next level.

The point is that I want the user to be able to define custom rules and events, and I'm not quite sure how to go about incorporating this functionality in my design. One idea I had was to create a Rule Object, which consists of a list of Predicates and a List of Actions, but I'm not quite sure where these rule objects should exists or where they should be checked/triggered, or if they're even a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The list of rules that a user can add needs to be a defined set, so the logic for each would be written into most relevant component.

The collision rule that you mention would be a part of the physics component, the speed rule would be part of a health component etc.

Comment: So the philosophy behind the ECS design is that there shouldn't be any logic in the Components or Entities. The idea is that the logic should be in different Systems. But even still, how would I allow the user to create custom rules? It seems that your suggesting that I implement the rules before hand..?

Comment: In the game engines I've worked with the logic is typically inside the components or entities.  Some of the components can get very specific though.  Even your custom rules can't be boundless, at the end of the day they need to modify a finite amount of properties.